# Smooth divisors in an ample linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth scheme over an algebraically closed field, and let $\mathcal{L}$ be an ample line bundle. Let us consider the linear system of divisors defined by sections of $\mathcal{L}$. I will denote this $|\mathcal{L}|$.

Is it guaranteed that there exists $D\in |\mathcal{L}|$ such that $D$ is smooth? If that is not the case, can we at least guarantee that $D$ is reduced?

Both statements are generally true if $\mathcal{L}$ is very ample, but I cannot seem to find a reference for ample $\mathcal{L}$. What can be said in this case?

Thanks for any help or direction

Comment: Have you thought of the possibility that $|\mathcal{L}|=\emptyset$?

Comment: Is your field of any characteristic, or char $0$?